# Enable transitive coverage as well as instruction level filtering in Java

Tags: java, maven, filtering, code-coverage, functional-testing

Migrated over to Software Recommendations: [ [Java code coverage library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9845/java-code-coverage-library) ]

---

I am trying to set up code coverage for a multi-module Java application. The application has integration/functional tests which span across modules. For example, `module-service`, `module-dao` and `module-api` would be exercised by a single functional test. I'm now trying to enable code coverage for this project.

I have the following requirements:

1. **Report transitive code coverage across all three modules:** Tests are present only in `module-service`, but they exercise code in the other two modules as well. I currently use JaCoCo for code coverage because it can calculate this transitive coverage through its run-time instrumentation feature.
2. **Filter out unwanted functions (not classes) from coverage:** A number of compile-time enhancer tools generate synthetic methods and/or code blocks in the compiled code. This skews coverage considerably for smaller classes.

What would be the best way to approach this? Is there any way to achieve both these objectives?

Comment: You want to eliminate the coverage data from "toString" methods because... it takes too much runtime space?  disk space? display space?  Why can't you just ignore it in the display?

Comment: @IraBaxter please check my edit - it seemed too long to put in as a comment.

Comment: I have edited my question to (I think) follow the guidelines. Let me know if anything else needs to be done.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this question is not "SO-worthy"? And what is the appropriate place for this question?

Comment: Yes. Your original question title said "...tool..." which SO people has decided you shouldn't ask. (I think this is crazy; programming is about using tools).  You've revised your question but its too late: a bunch of enforcers have piled onto you so your question loses.  You have revised your question so that it almost doesn't violate that rule; I'd suggest you add "any way to do that Jacoco" so they don't think you are asking for another tool indirectly.  Then you can go to MetaStack overflow as ask that your question be reinstated. FWIW, I voted to "reopen".

Comment: @IraBaxter thanks for the reply. I guess my question *is* about alternative "tools/libraries". I know for a fact that JaCoCo does not support this and there is a ticket open for it. Ah well.. *tumbleweed*

Comment: @IraBaxter On the plus side, I just discovered [Code Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66606/code-recommendations) and [Software Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) on Area51. Sounds like they fit the bill.. I'm going to copy-migrate my question there.